# AdMob delay notification payment

Tags: admob

I selected the new AdMob but I have old earnings from old AdMob.Does not transfer the earnings.
Every 2 of month I received notification email for payment, but now I have not receiving anything yet....Has anyone got payment notification email from old AdMob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received e-mail with **Payment Update** yesterday and I see 2 possibilities:

- You didn't exceed payment threshold ($100 in ACH/Wire)
- Delay might be caused by new admob update and you will receive e-mail today or tomorrow.

Anyway such delays has already occured in the past.

Comment: I have about 1000 $...you used tax id?

Comment: Last received: Payment for $410.51 by Paypal on 2013-08-02, complete.Without tax id.

Comment: I didn't fill tax id.

Comment: Maybe needs for more large amounts 1000$?

Comment: I don't think so, but it might depends on location. I'm from Europe.

Comment: I am stressed because upgrade to new AdMob...and old AdMob freeze with big amount....Europe too...

Comment: can any one tell me why Bank tell me that there is NO such amount credited from Admob while in my account 104 USD has been wired Transferred and ad mob generate bill also even  two time i have earned and both time ad mob release payment but Bank is telling there is NO such amount has been received please suggest why this happen